# Virtualbox and getting the Locked VT-x Error when trying to use more than 1 processor on the session

Tags: virtualbox, vt-x

I have installed the latest version of virtualbox onto my Hewlett Pakard (h8-1170uk)
I have a intel i7 2600 cpu and 8 gb of ram

I can get virtual box to create several sessions of different operating systems at the same time, but whenever i try to get 1 session to open up using more than 1 processor option select ( i wanted one of my session access to 2 processors ) i keep getting this error message

VT-x features locked or unavailable in MSR. (VERR_VMX_MSR_LOCKED_OR_DISABLED).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: Console
Interface: IConsole {1968b7d3-e3bf-4ceb-99e0-cb7c913317bb}

I have search many times and cannot find a option to correct this.
I have check my BIOS and there are no options about VT-x or Virtualisation or anything.

Am i doing something wrong ? Why does Virtualbox run fine when just using the 1 processor option ?

Answer (score 2):

VirtualBox needs "VT-x" support when virtualizing multicore. This is because software virtualization is a feat by itself, and because hardware support was becoming ubiquitous, it doesn’t make sense to develop and maintain multicore software virtualization for a marginal and dwindling number of users.

You processor have support for this "enterprise" feature.

Unfortunately, it seems that HP is disabling this "enterprise" feature at the BIOS level on most home desktops. ("Pavillon" is Home)

If you really don’t see the virtualization option in the Bios (I have access to almost the same computer, but sold for Small & Medium Businesses, and that option was available, but disabled by default), try a bios update.

It seems that some people are distributing BIOSes with that feature available, but I won’t advise for it: it’s sometimes impossible to recover from a bad BIOS flash.